# C# popular um combo box com variável double

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variáveis, combobox, double

Que fazer um combo box com vários valores de altura mas meu código não roda, o resulta só adiciona 1.47:

```
for(double i = 1.47; i <= 2.00; i++)
{
   cbxExemplo.Itens.Add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boas o teu problema encontra-se no incrementador utilizado(i++), visto que quando realizas a operação na primeira iteração do ciclo o valor é 1.47 no entando de acordo com o incremento i++ o valor na segunda iteração seria 2.47 e sendo a condição 2.47 <= 2.00 ele para-te o ciclo adicionado apenas o primeiro valor. Caso pretendas utilizar o codigo acima deves utilizar um incremento de i+= 0.01

```
for(double i = 1.47; i <= 2.00; i+=0.01)
{
   cbxExemplo.Itens.Add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom depois de quebrar muito a cabeça e testar vários códigos consegui isso espero que ajude alguém com o mesmo problema:

```
for(int i = 147; i <= 200; i++)
{
   double num = i;
   cbxExemplo.Itens.Add((num/100).ToString("N2"));
}
```